# Let $\langle G,*\rangle$ be an abelian group with identity element $e$. Prove that $H = \{x ∈ G | x ∗ x = e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $\langle G,*\rangle$ be an abelian group with identity element $e$. 
Prove that $H = \{x \in G | x ∗ x = e\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: As it stands, you just copy-pasted a textbook question without talking to us at all. This is known as a "problem statement question" (PSQ) and is frowned upon. Here are some things you should disclose: Do you understand the question? Do you know what a subgroup is? Do you have any experience testing if a subset is a subgroup? Do you know what you have to do to test if a subset is a subgroup? Have you tried anything? If you tried something, where did you get stuck? And so on.

Comment: [Prove that if $G$ is abelian, then $H = \{a \in G \mid a^2 = e\}$ is subgroup of $G$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/395747), [If $G$ is abelian, then the set of all $g \in G$ such that $g = g^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/146871), [Prove that $H = \{x \in G \mid  x=x^{-1}\}$ is a subgroup.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/203455)

Comment: In addition to @arctictern's comment I will add a link to: [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960). In the connection with the points he make, the [part about context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) seems to be most relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in an abelian group $x\mapsto x^2$ is a homomorphism since $(ab)*(ab) = (a*a)*(b*b)$. But then you can just recognize your set as the kernel of this homomorphism, hence a subgroup.

---

If you've never seen that kernels are subgroups, it's easy, if $x,y\mapsto e$ under a map $\phi$, then note that

> $$\phi(x*y^{-1}) = \phi(x)*\phi(y)^{-1} = e*e = e$$

And since clearly $e\in\ker \phi$ is non-empty, this proves it is a subgroup.

Comment: I imagine this sort of exercise could easily come even before homomorphisms are introduced.

Comment: @arctictern Most definitely. Since there's no context I provide the simplest proof.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As G is abelian, all subgroups' elements commute with each other. Can you see how to apply this to the problem at hand?

Comment: still confused. is it because a' = a?

Comment: @korn Let us go over the definition of a subgroup. Clearly, the set mentioned is a subset of the group. Because I did not read the question correctly (G is abelian), I mentioned the hint. But anyways, we can prove the existence of inverses: as you mentioned, $a^{-1} = a.$ Now all we have to do is prove closure - which you can do when the elements commute with each other. The existence of an identity is trivial to prove as well. I will leave the formalization of the proof up to you.